# Image Slider not loaded with Ajax request

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, slider

I'm trying to use an Image Slider from this link http://www.menucool.com/javascript-image-slider

I  created an index.html file that will be used to show all the pages, so the navigation is only by changing the `<div id="isi">` content. Here's the index file

```
<body class="wg">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <h1 class="banner-font">Header</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group button-banner">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="getSummary(1)"
                >Home</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="getSummary(5)">Contact Us</button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Tentang Kami <span class="caret"></span></button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="getSummary(2)">Sejarah</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="getSummary(3)">Visi Misi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="getSummary(4)">Program Studi</a></li>
                </ul>


            </div>
            <div id="isi">
                    <!-- ini isi nya -->
            </div>
            <footer>
                <b>
                    &copy; 2013 Kurnia Fredy Wijaya & Luki Ramadon <br>
                    Fakultas Teknik Universitas Pancasila
                </b>
            </footer>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                getSummary(1);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
```

On the page's first load, it will execute getSummary(1) method that will fetch data with ajax..here's the ajax code..

```
function getSummary(id){
if(id==1){
    alamat = "pages/home.html";
}
else if(id==2){
    alamat = "pages/sejarah.html";
}
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: alamat,
 data: "id=" + id, 
 success: function(data) {
      document.getElementById('isi').innerHTML = data;
      console.log(document.getElementById('isi'));
 }});}
```

And the image slider is located in pages/home.html..here's the code

```
        <div class="isiFrame">
        <div id="sliderFrame">
            <div id="slider">
                <a class="lazyImage" href="img/img1.jpg" title=""></a>
                <a class="lazyImage" href="img/img2.jpg" title=""></a>
                <a class="lazyImage" href="img/img3.jpg" title=""></a>
            </div>
        </div><br />
    </div>
```

When i try to run it on browser, the navigation works fine, but not the image slider. When i navigate to other page and then back to the page where the slider's on, the slider lags, it shows only the loading bar. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably have to re-initialize the slider when the content is updated. Add it to your ajax success callback:

```
...
success: function(data) {
      document.getElementById('isi').innerHTML = data;
      console.log(document.getEimageSlider.reload();
      imageSlider.reload();
...
```

http://www.menucool.com/slider/create-image-slider-dynamically

Comment: hey dude it works :D , now the slider shows up when i navigate it back.
but when i navigate it back, the sliding effects gone, it only changes the images, but without effects..am I missing something (again)?

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your script is on a different page.  I can't really tell from the way this is posted.

It could also be that you are using success for your ajax call, which from the looks of it is using the jquery library.  If you are in fact using the jquery library you should be using .done .fail .then etc.  Otherwise unless you re-call the ajax like @isherwood said to do, the success won't be called.

Comment: yes, i placed the script on a different page..would that be a problem??

Comment: yeah it can be.  The function that is being called would be local to that page.